# Cellular data use broken down by time and app / real time data alerts

Tags: android, ios

I want to reduce the amount of cellular data my family's phones use. We're a mixed household, so I'm interested in both iOS and Android options.

The cellular data settings let me see how much data each app is using, and I've found apps that let me see how much data I'm using per day. I am searching for software that can do either of the following:

1. Show per-day or per-hour data usage *by app*. That is, I can currently find out that I used a lot of data on August 20th, or that Facebook used a lot of data at an indeterminate time in the past, but neither of those is as useful as seeing how much data Facebook used on each individual day, so I can pinpoint spikes.
2. Provide close-to-real-time warnings about data usage. For example, I can currently sign up to get an alert from my provider when I've used, e.g., 500MB within one billing cycle. But it would be more useful if my phone could tell me that I've used 1MB within the last hour, or even notify me that my data usage has been higher than normal over the last few minutes.

Comment: For Android, you might take a look at [3G Watchdog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdog). AFAIK that comes pretty close (or even matches) your requirements. More alternatives in my app list [Statistics on data usage](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_statistics#group_93). (if you ask why I didn't write an answer: I'm not using such app, so I'm not sure it fits).

Comment: @Izzy The second link you give comes up with a security warning on my system.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Sorry, self-signed cert and I forgot to remove the "s" from "https". You can either switch to plain http (modify the URL), or accept the cert (view it to confirm: signed by IzzySoft). As soon as Mozilla's cert service becomes available (next month I'm told) I'll switch to "properly signed certs" :)